# Is it possible to retrieve multiple s3 objects with their metadata and tags?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Is it possible to retrieve multiple s3 objects with their metadata and tags? I can iterate headObject for 1000 files for example but it would also take very long time. What I am looking for any way for retrieving files in a way similar to listObjects or listObjectsV2 but with their metadata and tags. It's ok if it takes couple calls too but I am trying to learn if there are any other solution to iterate them all and asking one by one.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify... you are only seeking a listing of object name, metadata and tags? You are _not_ wanting to retrieve the object itself, right?

Comment: No you can not.

Comment: Yes I do not want to retrieve object itself. I want to save some extra tags and metadata with it and show it when I'm getting the folder list.